# Create a "Week-Year" column based on a datetime column to show only "YYYY-ww" format

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I would like to create a YrWeek column in YYYY-WW format, e.g. 2022-01, based on a Date column in YYYY-MM-DD format. I would like to keep the YrWeek column in datetime format, so it will make my life easier when I plot it out.

Below are the steps that I tried

First convert the Date to datetime64

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format = %Y-%m-%d)
```

Then tried the following codes that I research here and there but still cannot figure out a way to create the YrWeek column in YYYY-WW in datetime64 format

```
df['YrWeek'] = df.Date.dt.to_period('M') #this show 2021-01-01 to 2021-01-06 in the column and in the plot later

df['YrWeek'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.apply(lambda x:'{0}-{1}'.format(x.year, x.isocalendar().week)), format='%Y-%w', errors='coerce') # which return "NAT" in the column

df['Yrweek'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.dt.year.astype(str) + '-' + df.Date.isocalendar().week.astype(str), format='%Y-%w') # this seems an unsuccessful operation
```

Thanks first for your helps. I am quite sure I've seen it somewhere, but unable to recall it or get my head round on this issue at the moment.

thanks.

Comment: you have `dt.strftime` to convert a datetime dtype column to string, see also [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: @FObersteiner, thanks for your helps. Seems pandas have yet support %Y-%w in datetime format. The reason I want it in datetime instead of string format is because it will make the plotting a lot easier later on, instead of using the complicated mdates module from matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime),

> A datetime object is a single object containing all the information from a date object and a time object.

It is not likely to export YYYY-WW in datetime64 format, but you may use `strftime()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to create an explicit format string.

Here is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time': pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-01-31')})
df['YrWeek'] = df['date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%W')

df.head(5) # print sample result
   date_time   YrWeek
0 2022-01-01  2022-00
1 2022-01-02  2022-00
2 2022-01-03  2022-01
3 2022-01-04  2022-01
4 2022-01-05  2022-01
```

Comment: thanks for your helps. It seems the string object is my only choice at the moment. Thanks again any.